# Transactional dictionary

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, transactions, thread-safety

I've got a `IDictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>>` in my application. Users have requests like:

> I want to take out: n values of TKey=5 and m values of TKey=3.

However, the removal should only take place if *all* specified elements are present. If the dictionary would have n+3 values of TKey=5 but only m-1 values of TKey=3 *no* elements should be removed.

What's the best way to guarantee this transactional behavior? Would you lock the whole dictionary, then check if everything is present and then remove the elements if all specified queries are fulfilled?

Is there any way to make the dictionary somehow transactional? Something like:

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
  foreach(var query in queries)
    // try to remove elements of query -> exception if not possible -> all others are back in place

  tx.Commit(); // ok, all queries fulfilled, commit now
}
```

Or is it best practice to write a wrapper class for the dictionary which has a method `TakeFromDictionary(IEnumerable<Query> queriesWhichMustBeFulfilled)` which is thread-safe?

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juval Lowy has implemented transactional support for objects. He described his work in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163688.aspx
Within the code example he provides together with the article a `TransactionalDictionary<T,K>` is included.

```
var dictionary = new TransactionalDictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1, "A");

// #1: committed transaction
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    dictionary.Add(2, "B");
    dictionary.Add(3, "C");
    dictionary.Add(4, "D");
    scope.Complete();
}
Debug.Assert(dictionary[3] == "C");

// #2: uncommitted transaction
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  dictionary[1] = "Z";

  // transaction is not completed -> rollback to initial state 
  //scope.Complete();
}
Debug.Assert(dictionary[1] == "A");
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer, although it is not exactly what I expected or what I was looking for. Obviously transactional memory is not yet mainstream enough to be supported by more "enterprise-ready" libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a wrapper and handle the locking within the public methods of the wrapper.

This would also allow you to replace the dictionary if your requirements become to complex down the road. It implements the locking in one place without the caller having to worry about it.

Also, having a generic list inside a dictionary becomes hard to read (`new Dictionary<String, IList<Int32>>()`) - it could indicate that the dictionary is overloaded :-)